# Modifying .ui files requires a `make clean`

Tags: c++, qt

**The Problem**: When a QMainWindow or QDialog's corresponding .ui file has been altered in Qt Designer, the entire project must be cleaned and rebuilt in order for those changes to take effect: `make clean` then `make`. If the project isn't cleaned first, the changes will not reflect in the executable.

**The Project Structure**:

```
./
    project.pro
./include/
    MainWindow.h
    Main.h
./src/
    MainWindow.cpp
    Main.cpp
./ui/
    MainWindow.ui
```

**The Source**:

MainWindow.h:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, private Ui::MainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:

    MainWindow();
};
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    Ui::MainWindow::setupUi(this);
}
```

project.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG -= debug release
CONFIG += qt debug_and_release warn_on incremental flat link_prl embed_manifest_dll embed_manifest_exe
QT += xml xmlpatterns

INCLUDEPATH += include/
UI_DIR = include/

FORMS += ui/MainWindow.ui
HEADERS += include/MainWindow.h include/Main.h
SOURCES += src/MainWindow.cpp src/Main.cpp
```

Note: Include guards and class members have been stripped out for terseness.

**Update**:

Assuming that we edit MainWindow.ui in Designer, save it, and run a `make`, the following shell commands are executed (on a Windows platform; equal commands are executed on a 'nix box too):

```
QTDIR\bin\uic.exe ui\MainWindow.ui -o include\ui_MainWindow.h
QTDIR\bin\moc.exe ... include\MainWindow.h -o build\moc\moc_MainWindow.cpp
MSVS\bin\cl.exe /c ... -Fobuild\obj\ moc_MainWindow.cpp 
MSVS\bin\link.exe ... /OUT:bin\target.exe
```

The `uic` header generator has been run, and the window has been moc'ed. Despite this the window remains unchanged in the executable.

**Update #2**:

I found these lines in the Makefile:

```
####### Compile

build\obj\MainWindow.obj: src\MainWindow.cpp

build\obj\main.obj: src\main.cpp

build\obj\moc_MainWindow.obj: build\moc\moc_MainWindow.cpp
```

Bingo. `MainWindow.obj` rightfully depends on `MainWindow.cpp`, but not on `moc_MainWindow.cpp`. Changing the first line to `build\obj\MainWindow.obj: src\MainWindow.cpp build\moc\moc_MainWindow.cpp` rectified this whole issue.

**However**: the next time I run `qmake` it's going to nix me. What can I type in qmake to fix this permanently?

Comment: Actually, MainWindow.obj should depend on ui_MainWindow.h rather than moc_MainWindow.cpp.  (moc_MainWindow.cpp will be compiled separately, and linked in at the link step.)  Some thoughts: 1) Does your .pro file have a TARGET line? 2) You might need to add "core" and "gui" to the QT += line.

Comment: @piccy: I can confirm that QT contains gui core xml xmlpatterns. TARGET = app.

Comment: I can't reproduce the unwanted behaviour you are seeing using Qt4.8.4 on Mac - if I look at the standard Qt examples, e.g. `examples/designer/calculatorform`, it works as expected, even after adding your `UI_DIR` and `INCLUDEPATH` specification. Does this standard example work for you?  If so, you have something to work from/towards.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your UI_DIR should be set to ui, not include.

Comment: I see no evidence of that in the Qt documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that you remove from the config both "release" and "debug," then add to the config "debug_and_release." Running debug_and_release adds both of those configurations in, but swaps their order in the CONFIG.

It doesn't sound like that would trigger the dependency problem you are seeing, but it is worth a try, as far as I'm concerned.

By the way, you can always give qmake a try without blowing away your Makefile. Just run "qmake -o Makefile.foo" and it will save it to another file.

Comment: I'll give that a try in a day or two and see what happens. I've just learned to live with this, having had it happen for over a year. As for clearing release and debug from config... I've found the qmake documentation very good, except in regards to build modes, where the documentation is spectacularly bad. I don't remember the exact issue, but I had to clear them quite a long while back in order to get qmake to be happy about something, though I don't recall the exact issue at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with problems like this for some time and found out that, `DEPENDPATH` needs to point all directories with generated files/project headers. Otherwise qmake may skip some headers while generating dependencies in Makefile. Try adding `DEPENDPATH += include` in your .pro file